# Delete only the patterns and not the entire line

Tags: awk, sed

I have a text file as below

```
 OG1: Panda|Koala_1.2_animals Panda|Koala_extinct Elephant|Ostrich_1_0_mammal_bird
 OG2: Panda|Koala_1.2_animals Panda|Koala_cute Oyster|Ostrich_1_0_seafood_bird
 OG3: Panda|Koala_animals Platypus|Hummingbird_1_0_mammal_bird
 OG4: Platypus|Hummingbird_1_0_mammal_bird
```

I want to remove any word that starts with Panda|Koala until the space how many ever times the pattern appears to get

```
 OG1: Elephant|Ostrich_1_0_mammal_bird
 OG2: Oyster|Ostrich_1_0_seafood_bird
 OG3: Platypus|Hummingbird_1_0_mammal_bird
 OG4: Platypus|Hummingbird_1_0_mammal_bird
```

I tried using

```
sed'/Panda|Koala/d' data.txt
```

This deletes the entire line which contains the pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace with an empty string, use the replacement command `s/pattern/replacement/`:

```
sed 's/Panda|Koala[^ ]* *//g' data.txt
```

`[^ ]` means *a character that isn't a space* and `g` performs the replacement for all occurrences in the line.

Comment: `sed 's/Panda|Koala\S*\s*//g'` might be better to handle tabs as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print " "$1,$NF}' file

 OG1: Elephant|Ostrich_1_0_mammal_bird
 OG2: Oyster|Ostrich_1_0_seafood_bird
 OG3: Platypus|Hummingbird_1_0_mammal_bird
 OG4: Platypus|Hummingbird_1_0_mammal_bird
```